# HandleError Attribute not working in expected way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.Net MVC 2 web application where I have HomeController. Index method generates unauthorized exception. I have customErrors=on. Now I want to show a view Error.aspx in shared folder with Exception.Message. But I get Resource not found /Error in browser.

Note: I had gone through all the related links on StackOverflow.

any help?

Comment: Please post some code how you use the custom error attribute. And note that by default the attribute load the default `error.aspx` view. So be sure you don't have delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC project using the default visual Studio wizard
2. Modify the HomeController so that it looks like this:

   ```
   [HandleError]
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           throw new Exception("oops");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the following to the `<system.web>` section of web.config:

   ```
   <customErrors mode="On" />
   ```
4. Run the application
5. As expected the `~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx` is shown

Comment: Thanks. But I want to pass the Exception object to this error view so that I can display Message out of it.

Comment: @Morin, the exception object is already passed to the `Error.aspx` view by the `HandleError` action filter. This view is strongly typed to `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo`. So inside it you can simply: `<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Exception.Message) %>` to display the error message.